# Regex grouping around marker characters

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6

I am having a heck of a time pulling out the parts of this string I need using es6.

`{\fTimes New Roman|b0|i0|c0|p0;Another}` => 
`Times New Roman` `b0` `i0` `c0` `p0` `Another`

and when it's more complicated:

`{\fTimes New Roman|b0|i0|c0|p0;call.me({obj});}` => 
`Times New Roman` `b0` `i0` `c0` `p0` `call.me({obj});`

All I can get to work reliably is: `match(/[\w][0-9]/g)` => `["b0", "i0", "c0", "p0"]`

- How do I grab everything between `\f` and the first `|`
- anything after the first `;` to the last `}`

Comment: You need to include more examples. A specific regex would look like this: https://regex101.com/r/CRp3b0/3

Comment: @MYGz, That worked brilliantly actually. Thanks!

Comment: If it worked for you shall I post it as an answer?

Comment: Please do and I will upvote and mark correct.

Comment: Done. Go ahead.

Comment: Accept Bohemian's solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This captures your targets in groups 1 and 2:

```
\\f([^|]*)[^;]*;(.*)}
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/VLkDpoNQV5).

For example, given input:

```
{\fTimes New Roman|b0|i0|c0|p0;call.me({obj});}
```

Groups are:

1. `Times New Roman`
2. `call.me({obj});`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something verbose like this:

```
\{\\f(.*?)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)\;(.*?)\}$
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/CRp3b0/3